# jQuery blur event firing on load, instead of when expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm working on a project which will require some form validation, which I'm using jQuery for.
There's a field where a user will enter their email, and once they have filled out that field I want to check it.

Currently, the first part of my JavaScript looks like this:

```
$(window).load(function()
{
    var email = $("#registerEmail");
    email.blur(alert("stuff")); //will call a validation function
```

Right now, I get the "stuff" alert as soon as the page loads. My understanding was that blur would only fire once an element gained focus and then lost it -- am I misunderstanding this? Shouldn't this alert only execute once a user clicks or types in the email form and then clicks or types somewhere else, rather than immediately when the page loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually executing the alert function when you do it that way. You need to provide a function that can be called later. Do

```
email.blur(function () {
    alert("stuff");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had tried something like this before, but I must have been doing something else wrong...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#registerEmail").blur(function(){
            //your alert here
     });

});
```